# Keep the lines starting with a pattern in a text file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am working on a text file in JSON format. I would like to keep only the lines that start with this pattern:

{"MessageType": "SALES.CONTRACTS.SALECREATED"

Here you can see two lines of my data:

```
{"MessageType": "SALES.CONTRACTS.HOLDCREATED", "Event": {"Id": "ZWbDoMKQw6HDjFzCo8KuwpNmwofCjl7Co8OPwpDCncOSXMOdccKTZVVWZWbCnA==", "RefInfo": {"TenantId": {"Id": "ZMKXwpbClsOhwpNiw5E="}, "UserId": {"Id": "wpzCksKWwpbCpMKTYsKeZMKZbA=="}, "SentUtc": "2013-04-28T16:59:48.6698042", "Source": 1}, "ItemId": {"Id": 116228}, "Quantity": 1, "ExpirationDate": "2013-04-29T03:59:44.241", "Description": null}}

{"MessageType": "SALES.CONTRACTS.SALECREATED", "Event": {"Id": {"Source": 1, "SourceId": "ZGA=-3-1-002-0801743-2330650"}, "RefInfo": {"TenantId": {"Id": "ZGA="}, "UserId": {"Id": "ZGY="}, "SentUtc": "2013-01-14T15:39:03.5237879", "Source": 1}, "Status": {"Status": 3, "AutoRemoveInfo": null}, "Items": {"Items": [{"Id": {"Id": 1193}, "Sku": {"Sku": "Con BM20"}, "Quantity": 1, "UnitPrice": {"amount": 11.92, "currency": 840}}], "FulfilledItems": []}, "ShippingInfo": {"Carrier": "", "Class": "", "Region": null, "Country": 0, "PostalCode": null, "Costs": null, "Charges": null}, "SaleDate": "2013-01-13T13:39:57", "Kits": null, "Products": null, "AdditionalSaleInfo": null}}
```

The desired output for me will be:

```
{"MessageType": "SALES.CONTRACTS.SALECREATED", "Event": {"Id": {"Source": 1, "SourceId": "ZGA=-3-1-002-0801743-2330650"}, "RefInfo": {"TenantId": {"Id": "ZGA="}, "UserId": {"Id": "ZGY="}, "SentUtc": "2013-01-14T15:39:03.5237879", "Source": 1}, "Status": {"Status": 3, "AutoRemoveInfo": null}, "Items": {"Items": [{"Id": {"Id": 1193}, "Sku": {"Sku": "Con BM20"}, "Quantity": 1, "UnitPrice": {"amount": 11.92, "currency": 840}}], "FulfilledItems": []}, "ShippingInfo": {"Carrier": "", "Class": "", "Region": null, "Country": 0, "PostalCode": null, "Costs": null, "Charges": null}, "SaleDate": "2013-01-13T13:39:57", "Kits": null, "Products": null, "AdditionalSaleInfo": null}}
```

Using awk, sed or grep, how could I search my whole data.raw file to keep only the lines that start with the desired pattern? I would like to save the result in a new.raw file.

Answer (score 0):

Simple ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '/"MessageType": "SALES\.CONTRACTS\.SALECREATED"/' inputfile > newfile
```

---

***sed*** approach:

```
sed '/"MessageType": "SALES\.CONTRACTS\.SALECREATED"/!d' inputfile > newfile
```